# Cascade save model not saving relationship

Tags: postgresql, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.4

I have an Play2 application using eBean integrated with PostgreSQL database.

Basically I have a model `TripRequest` that as a list of `Passenger`s . The use case is "A trip has several passengers".

For the `TripRequest` I have this model:

```
@Entity
public class TripRequest extends Model {

    enum Status {
        OPEN,
        PROCESSING,
        CLOSED,
        CANCELLED
    }

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private User owner;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tripRequest")
    @JoinTable(name = "trip_passengers")
    private List<Passenger> passengers;
    (... other fields, getters and setters ...)
```

And this is my `Passenger` model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trip_passenger")
public class Passenger extends Model {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TripRequest tripRequest;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    (... other fields, getters and setters)
```

So, I create a new instance of `TripRequest`, several instances of `Passenger` and set that list as the passengers of `TripRequest`instance.
Problem is that when I do `tripRequest.save()` everything in the main instance (`TripRequest`) gets saved but the relations are not (so the passengers list).

I read in the documentation and examples and everything is pointing me to the `CascadeType.ALL` in the `@ManyToOne` annotation but no "luck" at all

EDIT: if you think the complete classes are useful please let me know as I can post them. Just decided to keep the example short so I trimmed them.

Comment: Is the result the same if the cascade is placed on the `@OneToMany` instead?

Comment: @jsonmurphy I get a NullPointerException as described in https://gist.github.com/mribeiro/2627ecb640bf19e0adb6

Answer (score 1):

Your @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tripRequest") ... has no cascade = CascadeType.ALL (or CascadeType.PERSIST).

This means the save on TripRequest is not cascading on the list of passengers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set `tripRequest` on `Passenger` side (cause this class actually owns the relationship) and only then save it. Something like this:

```
for(Passenger p : passengers){
    p.tripRequest = this;
}
```

Comment: I am setting the tripRequest instance on each passenger. However, when I save the tripRequest the passengers list isn't saved. A workaround I found is to save the tripRequest and then iterate thru the passengers and save each individually, but it feels "wrong"

Comment: @MiguelRibeiro That is definitely wrong. I think everything will work without double save if you put `(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` to the `@OneToMany` annotation of `TripRequest` instead of `@ManyToOne` of Passenger. Because this is the direction of the cascading.

Comment: Well... found the issue. I don't even need to set the tripRequest instance to the Passenger. So, 1st of all, the cascade must go to the `@OneToMany`. The problem is that the `Passenger` didn't have an ID member. I had to debug Play's code to see from where the NPE was coming.